# I have two datasets both have the same column names do I have to rename them or combine them in order to process them in the model

Tags: python

I have two datasets, `Task1A_train.csv` and `Task1A_test.csv`.  Both have the same column names. Do I have to rename them or combine them in order to process them in the model?

The first one is:

```
    x1      y
0   1960.0  0.71
1   1960.5  0.85
2   1961.0  0.61
3   1961.5  0.92
4   1962.0  0.72
```

And the second looks like this:

```
    x1      y
0   1960.25 0.63
1   1960.75 0.44
2   1961.25 0.69
3   1961.75 0.55
4   1962.25 0.77
```

Sorry for the elementary question but I appreciate any help.

Comment: What you want to do with the dataframes? you want to stack them vertically or horizontally?

Comment: As long as they are a train set and a test set, they don't have to be in the same dataframe. Provide more info about what you want to do and what model do you use.